# Use case where MAC and DAC complement each other

Tags: access-control

We can implement MAC (Mandatory Access Control) and DAC (Discretionary Access Control) together and they can complement each other. My understanding is when MAC is there it overrides everything. Can anyone help me understand how they can work together?

Answer (score 1):

SELinux policy rules are checked after DAC rules.
SELinux policy rules are not used if DAC rules deny access first.